# htaccess PNG as PHP?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hi I'm trying to get my webserver to point to a PHP file when going to signature.png?name=test

I currently have this in my .htaccess:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .png
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /var/www
RewriteRule ^signature\.png$ signature.php?name=$1
```

It seems to be ignoring the .htaccess file though, but I tested and I know mod_rewrite is enabled. (I have looked elsewhere, but so far nothing has fixed it)

Comment: Didn't give me an error with garbage, guess it's not working. Could I possibly put the rules into my apache.conf or is that a terrible idea?

Comment: Putting it in `apache.conf` is also fine, you just need to restart it while testing

Comment: .htaccess is good for "temporary" overrides, e.g. development. permanent overrides should go into a .conf file, as .htacess processing adds a bunch of overhead to every http request.

Comment: Putting it in the conf file solved it. Thanks a lot :)